# What is the complete, authoritative way in which Mac OSX 10.9 and later builds its PATH?

Tags: macos, path

I have read just about every article on this subject.  To wit, I know about:

- `launchctl setenv`
- `/etc/launchd.conf`
- `/etc/paths`
- `/etc/paths.d/*`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/bashrc`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/.MacOSX/environment.plist`

Let's start whittling all this craziness down:

- From other reading, I know that on Mavericks anything that relies on an `environment.plist` is no longer supported or read.
- I know that `/etc/profile` erases any `PATH` previously set by `launchctl setenv` or present in `/etc/launchd.conf`, and uses a default set of paths appended with anything found in `/etc/paths.d/*` and `/etc/paths`.
- I also know that applications launched via Spotlight or the Dock obviously don't read your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

That leaves `launchctl setenv` and `/etc/launchd.conf` (same thing, really).

At any rate, in my case I find that in a Terminal window—I should stress I have none of the following files: `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `./bash_profile`—I find that the output of `env | grep PATH` has `/opt/subversion/bin` appended to the end of it.  This string does not show up in any of the sources listed above, so it must be coming from somewhere else.  I was not aware of there being anywhere else for it to come from.

So then: how does Mac OS X Mavericks build its `PATH` variable?

Comment: Where did you get your installation of subversion?

Comment: Found the root of my own personal problem: there was an emacs backup file in `/etc/paths.d` that had the old information in it that was not being shown by `ls` given the way I was invoking it.  I'd still be interested in the full list, which I've never seen anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to understand the theory and that's great.  I'll just say that from practical experience, you can modify `.bashrc`, `.profile` and/or `.bash_profile` and the path setting will stick.  I prefer `~/.profile` simply out of habit.  My teammates all use `.bash_profile`.  Either way it works as long as you pay attention to the order of processing precedence.

Here are a few other thoughts on the matter:

- [Homebrew wants me to amend my PATH (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/homebrew-wants-me-to-amend-my-path-no-clue-how)
- [How to correctly add a path to PATH (stackexchange)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi; thanks for your answer.  The `PATH` setting in that case won't stick for my Emacs.app launched from the Dock or from Spotlight.  Since I don't want to have duplicate `PATH` entries in both `/etc/launchd.conf` and `~/.profile`, I was hoping for the full startup sequence to see if I could find the common denominator.

Comment: what if you modify .profile to include what you want, use Automator to call a shell script that simply says `bash open -fa /Applications/Emacs.app` (or whatever the path is) and see if that works.  Or maybe there's a PATH option buried somewhere in the Emacs Preferences?